# In Matlab, what is ~m file?

Tags: git, matlab, file, repository, matlab-compiler

What does the ' ~ ' sign mean at the end of the file name?

[image]

BONUS QUESTION: How can I add files to the git repository without adding those '~' files?

Comment: How do I get the bonus points to answer the bonus question?

Comment: First you answer, then you get my prayers (and upvote) ;)

Answer (score 4):

That is a backup file, and if I am not mistaken it is actually from unix system and not matlab. On windows the backup files are `*.asv`. If you close your file the backup should disappear.

If you asking about version control, I would suggest you ignore all backup files by adding a like to `.gitignore` as follows: `*.m~`.

Comment: +1. If I can also make a suggestion, go to http://www.gitignore.io for premade templates for `.gitignore` files for different kinds of languages. You can also chain multiple languages together to make one composite `.gitignore` if you are developing in multiple languages.  For MATLAB, these not only include backup files, but any MEX generated backup files, Simulink backup files and so on.  This is what the MATLAB template for a `.gitignore` would generate: https://www.gitignore.io/api/matlab

Comment: @rayryeng I had only added `*~`, and that way you ignore all backups .mex's .cpp and any backup. But you are right for matlab specific one would be with only with `.m~`. Btw this is very useful list of useful [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Comment: Ah I see. I apologize. Please revert my changes.